# TypeScript : How to define a new Type can be undefined also

Tags: typescript

In my project I am converting a Scala code to a TypeScript Code.

Now in Scala language there is a prefined type called Option.
Option means it can be a type or can have undefined also.

In TypeScript we typically write it like this:

```
var myVar : MyType | undefined = await methodCall(...)
```

And the methodCall can be something like this:

```
function methodCall(...) : Promise<MyType | undefined>
{
   ........
   // The body of function
}
```

So now I am looking for a way in TypeScript to represent this `Scala Options` in such a way I can define a type something like this:

Problem Statement:

```
MyTypeOption ... it can be of MyType or undefined
```

Any suggestion how can I do it in TypeScript code?

So far the code I am doing in usual typeScript way:

```
var myVar : MyType | undefined = await methodCall(...)

function methodCall(...) : Promise<MyType | undefined>
{
   ........
   // The body of function
}
```

Comment: I'm surely misunderstanding the question, but why `type MyTypeOption = MyType | undefined` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a helper type that union's an arbitrary type with `undefined`:

```
type Option<T> = T | undefined;

const n: number = undefined; // Error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

const o: Option<number> = undefined; // Okay

type MyType = string;

type MyTypeOption = Option<MyType>;

async () => {
    var myVar = await methodCall();
    myVar.charAt(0); // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
}

async function methodCall(): Promise<MyTypeOption> {
    return undefined;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFQHxQLxQygB8oBXFAEwgDMEUIKBuAKGYGNUBnYKFALl6kAtgCMIAJzxlKNOg0ZQA9IqgBRceKTiBGcNADk5KrXoV9UBJ15IeAQ06cEAcxS2RAG2jAkUUJCj6KMJi4voAdKwcKNxQSAJwiKhoQaISOPhGsqYKyrAA1rYgzLlQpQB6APysftAAsiC6-vjc4nROLMw1UPWNEAnIKFL9ST16WB32IChsUAAUAJR4OADezKWlAG62kkIgAGrbUrYA7rYIPEIQwAAWSBQAwrbu7gss60oqUJVr67sH4mE2NdtgBBYCzAAM8xyKnUmm0sBEACsIGweJYoGAkA4EB4QAFMiYGOFmABfViTaZQajkNEDKCXG53R7PBYCAAKmiElggaFGkGGKBWP1K4iupHEg0JciYZOYQA)